# Found this is an old code base and am wondering if it is legit: if ($foo =~ "bar" and "baz") {

Tags: perl, string-matching

In an old Perl code base, there is this:

```
if ($foo =~ "bar" and "baz") {
```

and it works!  If I replace the quotes with the more common delimiter, /, it does not work.  Anyone recognize this syntax?  I cannot find any discussion of using "and" this way with the binding operator.  It also works if I chain on a second "and" but it does not work if I try "and not".  I was surprised to see this code and even more surprised to see that it works equivalently to:

```
if ($foo =~ /bar/ && $foo =~ /baz/) {
```

Is this legitimate syntax and if so, where can I find it documented?  Or is it extremely bad form and in need of being re-worked?

Comment: By "works", I mean the conditional path is taken.  When the string held in $foo contains both an instance of "bar" and an instance of "baz" the conditional steps are executed but not otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 if ( $foo =~ "bar" and "baz" )
```

is equivalent to

```
 if ( ( $foo =~ "bar" ) and "baz" )
```

Since `"baz"` always returns a true value, the above are equivalent to

```
 if ( $foo =~ "bar" )
```

For example,

```
use feature qw( say );

if ( $ARGV[0] =~ "bar" and "baz" ) {
   say "match";
} else {
   say "no match";
}

if ( $ARGV[0] =~ /bar/ && $ARGV[0] =~ /baz/ ) {
   say "match";
} else {
   say "no match";
}
```

```
$ perl a.pl oooooo
no match
no match

$ perl a.pl ooobarooo
match
no match

$ perl a.pl ooobazooo
no match
no match

$ perl a.pl ooobarbazooo
match
match
```

I wouldn't call that "working".

Comment: Well that would seem to make sense but I don't think that is the way it is behaving.  I will investigate further.

Comment: Added to my answer.

Comment: Well, sometimes I just need to have the obvious pointed out to me.  I apologize for taking your time.  I should have drilled down on this without this forum.  I was fooled because I was getting the right result and using a poor analysis.  Many thanks for your answer and good to know you are here.